# How can I view Accordion in Razor view MVC?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, .net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am so confuse about how to view Accordion in razor view from database?

I want to have a list of accordion base on one field in the database example and dynamically.

Which model? Should I send to the view? Can I send the `IENumerable` (list) for example? And how can I view it in a Razor page?

For example if I send the list like the picture to the view:

[image]

In the list as you can see, I have many season with seasonid and seasonName. And I want each seasonid is an accordion item in the razor view.

Do I or should I have to change the model I send to the view?

Thanks all

I have send the @model IEnumerable to the view and view it like this, but if I want to view each season as a accodition item. Do I need to change the model i send to the view or use directly C# in razor page?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial on how to ask. I understand you have problems with this but there is a lot of help in google about this topic, and you are asking a lot of question. You have to show some effort in order we can help you with a specific question.

Comment: I have update my question. In fact I am not sure what model should i send to the view to display list of accodition item easily.

Comment: If you have that doubt, is because you need to learn what means MVC. There is a lot of information

Comment: If i send @model IEnumerable<MatchViewModel> to the view, and I can view each match as a row, but now i want to view each season as accordion-item and each mach is a row in the body. Do I need to change the model that i send to the view or directly using C# on the razor page?